# Making a view at least a minimum size or invisible with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a grid cell that is primarily a photo, with a label for a description along the bottom.
Using auto layout, I want to define some rules that will make sure the label is either a minimum size (say 30px high), or invisible.

That is, if the cell is shrunk to a point that the description becomes illegible, I want it to disappear.

Is there a combination of constraints and priorities that will pull that off?

Comment: A picture would help to understand the case faster and would improve your question. Could you please add one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by just setting some constraints. But you could add a height constraint to your label, make it accessible in code, set it to be greater than or equal than your minimum size (or maybe one point below that). That'll make sure it's allowed to resize the same way it was before.

After that add a key value observation for it's constant and in the observation method set the view's alpha to zero (you can get the view by calling `heightConstraint.firstItem` if its shrinking below your desired threshold. (You might also set it's hidden property to YES, but I've experienced that a hidden view doesn't properly resize while hidden, haven't figured out why yet)...

Edit: Sry I got sth. wrong, of course you'd have to observe the actual height of the labels frame instead of the constraint's constant, because the constant doesn't change when the label resizes...